# Return the column letter rather than number with column "AA" onwards

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using 
`=CHAR(COLUMN(A1)+96)`

To return the column letter, which is fine in the instance above.

However, once the column goes beyond `Z` into `AA` and so on, the column letter will not return properly.

I understand why, as it has reached the end of the alphabet set and beyond that are other characters.

Is there another way to accurately return the column letter?

Comment: The question, why you want it.  If it is to use in another formula then there are better ways.  So, Is the final output the column, or do you use it in another formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternate method of getting the column letter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(A1)+26,4,1),1,"")
```

However, as Scott has already pointed out, depending on the need, there is probably a better way to accomplish your end goal.

Comment: Never mind, had not had my caffeine yet.  As always your formulas are more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

To get the column letter use this:

```
=LEFT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(A1),4,1),IF(ISNUMBER(--MID(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(A1),4,1),2,1)),1,2))
```

If you want it in lower case:

```
=LOWER(LEFT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(A1),4,1),IF(ISNUMBER(--MID(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(A1),4,1),2,1)),1,2)))
```

But as I said in my comment if you want to use it in another formula there are quicker and better methods.

Comment: Yes it will be used within an array formula that searches a sheet. Here is the code for interest `=CHAR(SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($AK$11, INDIRECT($AA$998&"A1:AE9999"))),1*COLUMN(INDIRECT($AA$998&"A1:AE9999"))),ROWS(A$1:A1))+96)`

Comment: Again this is just returning the column letter, what are you doing with that output?  Is this the final output or do you refer to it in another formula that uses INDIRECT?

Comment: `=IFERROR(IF(OR(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(INDIRECT($AA$2 & $AG$4 & B4),2)))=FALSE,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(INDIRECT($AA$2& $AG$4 & B4)," ",""))>3),"0",RIGHT(INDIRECT($AA$2& $AG$4 & B4),2)),0)` The "letter finder" formula is in cell `AG4` `AA2` is a sheet name. `B4` is a row number

Comment: I would ask a new question,  How to combine these two formula to avoid as many volatile functions as possible.  Include some test data and expected outcome, as well as a narrative of what you are trying to achieve.  Do not change this question to that, ask a new one and refer back to this one.  For this one choose the best answer,<cough>tigeravatar</cough>, as correct.  There is a way using INDEX that can most likely do this in one Formula. And get rid of some of the volatile functions, not all as your sheet name is variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want it but this will get it for you The cell being referenced here is D1):

`=MID(CELL("address",ASD1),2,FIND("$",RIGHT(CELL("address",ASD1),LEN(CELL("address",ASD1))-2)))`