# Combining or removing volatile functions/Outputting a column letter greater than Z

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Following on from advice given on this question:
[Return the column letter rather than number with column "AA" onwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893171/return-the-column-letter-rather-than-number-with-column-aa-onwards)

I have the following formula:
`=CHAR(SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($AK$11, INDIRECT($AA$998&"A1:AE9999"))),1*COLUMN(INDIRECT($AA$998&"A‌​1:AE9999"))),ROWS(A$‌​1:A1))+96)`

In essence it will search the sheet given in `AA998` and the range `A1:AE9999` for the word/phrase specified in `AK11` and return the column number, then the column number is converted to its column letter.

This is necessary as I need to use it as part of an `INDIRECT` in the formula below:

`=IFERROR(IF(OR(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(INDIRECT($AA$2 & $AG$4 & B4),2)))=FALSE,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(INDIRECT($AA$2& $AG$4 & B4)," ",""))>3),"0",RIGHT(INDIRECT($AA$2& $AG$4 & B4),2)),0)`

This formula will check to see `IF` the right 2 characters of the destination cell are not numbers `OR` the contents of the cell are greater than 3 characters. If either are `true` just output 0. If `false` output the right 2 most characters.

My first formula is in cell `AG4`.
 `AA2` is a sheet name. `B4` is a row number

Example of use:

The sheet name that the `INDIRECT` refers to, contains columns of data. 
Lets say 5 columns with the first row containing the titles; Blue, Red, Yellow, Green, Orange.
Underneath the titles are data. The data is inconsistent and could mostly be junk so I want to extract only specific data in specific cells (Criteria in my 2nd formula)
Also, the columns could be in a different order, e.g Red, Orange, Yellow, Blue, Green.

Now, lets say `AK11` contains `Yellow`. My first formula will look for the column containing `Yellow` as the title and return the letter, my second formula now takes this letter (Along with sheet name and row number) and perform its checks. If the checks are ok, then output the right 2 numbers of the target cell.

Problem 1:
The first formula will not return a column letter greater than `Z`, so if the results of the search is in column `AA` this will not be the output. Ruining all subsequent formula. How can I obtain the actual column letter?

Problem 2:
How can I combine or improve these formula to remove some of the volatile functions or make the formula more efficient overall?

Answer (score 1):

To do it all in a single formula:

```
=IF(OR(NOT(ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(INDEX(INDIRECT($AA$998&"A1:E999"),B4,MATCH("*"&AK11&"*",INDIRECT($AA$998&"A1:E1"),0)),2))),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(INDIRECT($AA$998&"A1:E999"),B4,MATCH("*"&AK11&"*",INDIRECT($AA$998&"A1:E1"),0))," ",""))>3),0,--RIGHT(INDEX(INDIRECT($AA$998&"A1:E999"),B4,MATCH("*"&AK11&"*",INDIRECT($AA$998&"A1:E1"),0)),2))
```

However, I would recommend splitting it into two formulas anyway, so that we don't have to keep calling the `Index(Indrect(...` over and over.  So in your first formula cell (mentioned as AG4):

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT($AA$998&"A1:E999"),B4,MATCH("*"&AK11&"*",INDIRECT($AA$998&"A1:E1"),0))
```

And then in the second formula cell:

```
=IF(OR(NOT(ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(AG4,2))),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(AG4," ",""))>3),0,--RIGHT(AG4,2))
```

Note that these formulas assume the headers are in row 1 of the data sheet as stated in your example.

Comment: What would need to be done if the headers were not in row 1? As in my other question finding and returning the row was not an issue, so I didn't post the code but it is `=SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($AK$5, INDIRECT($AA$2&"A1:AE9999"))),1*ROW(INDIRECT($AA$2&"A1:AE9999"))+1),ROWS(A$1:A1))` However, I will now need to a find the row as well as the column if I am to do it this way.